# Windows 8 will not defrag or analyze system hard drive

Tags: windows-8, defragment, optimize

I recently bought a new laptop that runs windows 8. It has been about a month and I wanted to clean the system up a bit to keep it running smooth. I tried to defrag the system hard disk drive but when I click "analyze" or "optimize" the optimize drives window disappears for a millisecond then reappears and states the system still "needs optimization". It doesn't matter how many times I click on "optimize" It simply repeats the previous event. I can clean my removable disk and recovery hard drive without a problem.

Why won't it let me clean the system hard drive?

Comment: Is your main hard drive a SSD or traditional HD?

Comment: Windows 8 defragments system drives on a regular schedule, so there is no need to run a manual defrag. By default it runs weekly. On top of that, defragmentation does not add any noticeable system speed increase, unless you are running very old hardware and software.

Comment: @moses That makes sense to me, but why would it still think it needs optimizing afterwards then?

Comment: @kasekris If your new laptop is only a month old there is definitely no need for defragmentation.

Comment: I realize that there wasn't a need to defrag it, more curious than anything else, and its on a traditional HD.

Comment: it's just very odd that it won't do it. ... i set the auto defrag once a day, to see if the auto mode would just take care of it. it didn't.. its very odd

Comment: Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: i dont think that would work it happens too fast to capture

Comment: @kasekris I meant the window before you click 'analyze'.

Comment: @Simon: "If your new laptop is only a month old there is definitely no need for defragmentation" – Really? Without knowing *anything* about the usage pattern how can you be so sure?

Comment: @Karan I was under the impression that defragmentation is needed at best twice a year (for desktops at least with traditional HDs), for laptops it might be different. Before carrying out a defrag it best to "clean up" with a program like CCleaner, then reboot, then defrag. Even then there will not be a significant performance boost as indicated by moses in his coments above. I could be wrong.

Comment: @Simon: There's no fixed time period for ending up with high levels of fragmentation, since it obviously depends upon the amount of data and especially usage patterns. I defrag manually whenever I notice that one of my mechanical drives is getting *heavily* fragmented, which could be once a month or once a year. As for precisely quantifying the performance boost, I don't think we can generalise that either.

Comment: @Karan I suppose I was making a generalisation & of course it depends on usage patterns - agreed

Answer (score 7):

Try running a manual check and defrag using the command line `defrag` tool. You will need privileged command line, to access it:

- Open Start screen and type `cmd`
- One item should appear, right-click on it
- Choose *Run as Administrator* and confirm.

Then type the command you want and confirm it with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

To analyze drive:

```
defrag c: /a /u /v
```

This will provide a verbose report of the fragmentation of the drive.

To force a defrag:

```
defrag c: /d /v /x
```

This will defrag C: plus consolidate free space and provide a verbose report.

I would recommend a backup and a `chkdsk` before the defrag simply because you have unusual behavior from the GUI based defrag option. The latter can be run from privileged command line by executing `chkdsk c: /r`

Once this is complete, reboot your system and then check with the GUI options to see if you have the same behavior. Just keep in mind that it may take a long time to complete the defrag depending on the current state. You may want to run it overnight and check the following day.

Comment: defrag c: /d /v /x doesn't work for me. defrag c: /d /v does though